# Reset fork to be the same as current original project (git)

Tags: git

I forked a project on github.com. Started to write code. committing and pushing it on my own forked version. However, then the original project's technology changed  so that all folders deleted and created new ones. I did the same on my side, deleted folders and created new folders and files, but now I can't do pull requests because they are connected to the old version of the original project. How to update my fork so that it will be the same as curren't original project's version?

Comment: the easiest thing to do is probably to delete your fork and re-create it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to keep the commits you made, the simplest way is to delete your local repository and do a fresh clone of the project.

If your commits were done on `master` and you want to keep them in a `backup_branch`, simply do :

- `git checkout -b backup_branch master`

Then, to have your fork at the same point as the original project, do :

- `git fetch` // Fetch new commits from remote repository
- `git branch -D master` // Delete the `master` branch (it's just a branch like others)
- `git checkout -b master origin/master` // Recreate `master` from remote `origin/master`

You can also repeat this operation for others branches than `master` if you need.

Comment: Can you explain what can be the motivation to save the backup_branch? I noticed that commits performed on master that were accepted as pull requests appears on the original project commit list and as part of pull request history. Deleting the master branch will somehow affect the history on the original project?

Comment: If you've done commits on `master` branch, but you don't have shared them, deleting `master` would make your local commits hard to recover, since you don't have a branch reference on them. If this occurs, `git reflog` is the solution.

Comment: Ok, I imagined that this would happen to unshared commits. But what about the ones that were accepted by the original project? Will also disappear from the original project history?

Comment: No, they will stay. A commit stays in a repository as long as it's an ancestor of an existing branch or tag of this repository. A pull request merge tranforms PR's commits into target branch ancestors. As such, it's perfectly normal to see them into live branch history. Hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe the last step should be changed to "... // Recreate master from remote origin/master **after deleting your remote repo and forking it again**" as replacing 'origin/master' with 'upstream/master' on the last line doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You probably either want to merge in the changes or start fresh. Merging the changes can be done like this:

```
git merge {remote}/{branch}
```

Where `{remote}` is the git remote that points to the upstream repository (probably `origin` if you `git clone`d the upstream repo), and `{branch}` is the branch you want to merge in changes from. If you have no idea what this is, it's fairly likely to be `master`.